# Google Cloud Platform - Can SSH as root but not as user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Other than using root, I am unable to SSH into my instance as a normal user without getting the error "packet_write_wait: Connection to *.*.*.* port 22: Broken pipe".

I have added the generated SSH key into the console, but still have no luck.

Anything relating to this Broken Pipe part of the error that I'm seeing is talking about tweaking the ClientAliveInterval and ServerAliveInterval values, but I don't see why I would be able to get in as root if that were the case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Broken Pipe error message normally refers to a network connection issue. This specific error seems to be referring to a permission issue. When you connect with a non root user, there is a problem writing to the folder where the connection is directing.

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220104/write-failed-broken-pipe-when-trying-to-login-through-ssh-with-a-specific-use) that has a similar error / issue to yours . The folder where your users are being directed through SSH does not provide them with write permissions, this needs to be changed.

Comment: The info in that thread did the trick - thank you!!